# how to select parent div with jquery and close all siblings

Tags: jquery

I have that problem, in html I have this code:

```
<div>
     <div class='category' style="display:block">
        <div> <div onclick="closeOtherCategoryDiv($(this))">Name</div> </div>
        <div class="groups"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='category' style="display:block">
        <div> <div onclick="closeOtherCategoryDiv($(this))">Name</div> </div>
        <div class="groups"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='category' style="display:block">
        <div> <div onclick="closeOtherCategoryDiv($(this))">Name</div> </div>
        <div class="groups"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if I click on div with function closeOtherCategoryDiv($(this)) I want to set style attribute display:none for all another div.category except clicked.

Comment: what have u tried so far? can u show ur code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use inline scripts - jQuery makes it far easier to select elements without resorting to this.

Second, take a look at the dom traversal methods here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

9 times out of 9, everything you need to select can be done with a combination of those methods.

Third, try something like this:

### Script:

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(e){
        $('.toggle').not($(this)).hide();
    });
});
```

### HTML:

```
<div>
         <div class='category' style="display:block">
            <div> <div class='toggle'>Name</div> </div>
            <div class="groups"></div>
        </div>

        <div class='category' style="display:block">
            <div> <div class='toggle'>Name</div> </div>
            <div class="groups"></div>
        </div>

        <div class='category' style="display:block">
            <div> <div class='toggle'>Name</div> </div>
            <div class="groups"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And for the love of all that is good and holy in this world, remove the inline scripts.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#childDiv').parent().siblings.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function closeOtherCategoryDiv($this) {
 var filter = 'div.category';
 $this.closest(filter).siblings(filter).hide();
}
```

Additionally, consider setting that event handler through jQuery's `.on` instead of inline.

Answer (score 0):

With your HTML a little changed:

```
<div class='categories'>
    <div class='category'>
        <div> <div class='name'>Name</div> </div>
        <div class="groups"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='category'>
        <div> <div class='name'>Name</div> </div>
        <div class="groups"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='category'>
        <div> <div class='name'>Name</div> </div>
        <div class="groups"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handle clicks on elements with class "name" inside container with class "categories"
    $('.categories').on('click', '.name', function(e) {
        // Hide all categories
        $('.category').hide();
        // Show this category
        $(e.target).parents('.category').show();
    });
});
```

By using jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and specifying only one event handler, this should be performing well regardless of the number of categories you show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('.category').click(function() {
       $('.category').hide();
       $(this).show();
    });
});
```

hope this help..........